# botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm downloading files from AWS S3 Bucket like so:

```
import boto3

s3client = boto3.client("s3")
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

bucket_name = 'practice_bucket'
bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)

for obj in bucket.objects.all():
    filename = obj.key.rsplit('/')[-1]
    s3client.download_file(bucket_name, obj.key, "/txt/" + filename)
```

When attempting to place some files under a subdirectory, e.g. `/txt/`, I get the error:

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (404) when calling
> the HeadObject operation: Not Found

Oddly, it works on other file types using the same method, but doesn’t work for ones with `.json` extension.

What could be the issue? I even tried without placing them in an absolute subdirectory path, and I get no error and downloads the file onto the same directory as the script downloading. But when I actually define the path to download the file to, I get the error.

Comment: I just tried your code and it worked fine.  If you are getting the 404 error, that means there is some mismatch between the requested key and the actual key.

Comment: This question should be reopened. I have the same problem. He provided the desired behavior, the specific problem, and the error, as well as code. I am goping to have to go make another ticket for the exact same problem now. My key matches. I logged it to make sure.

Comment: Me too @ChristopherPisz. I have the same problem. Perhaps that is the AWS issue? I have been using my code in 5 months and it works well until today, I got that error. I actually don't know why?

Comment: Seems related to permissions in my case. I remade the lambda permission policies and it started working again.

Comment: Check this link out for `404` [Accessing a Bucket](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/migrations3.html?#accessing-a-bucket) Hope it helps

Comment: I ran into this issue when passing a folder as the second argument to download_file. Programmer mistake, but also a rather cryptic error

Comment: Happened to me too. For me it works when the key does not start as an absolute path, ie it does not start with "/".

Comment: I get this error on production side, in dev side I do not get it, however both codes are identical... both run in windows, I cannot figure out what the difference is...

Comment: @JJCV : Thank you for your valuable comment. I just used the urllib.parse's urlparse and it puts the `/` in the front of the key. The error should be different to be honest.

Comment: I got this error when I accidentally misspelled the file name for the file I was downloading.

Comment: I encounter same issues even I passed correct parameters `api_params = {'Bucket': 'file-exporter', 'Key': 'e_group.json'}`. Just, difference is I am using async approach.

Comment: For me the answer was that the path to my s3 container's volume was wrong, so the file I was trying to open didn't exist. Another reopen vote here -- not just a comment, I actually voted.

Comment: If anyone is getting this on DigitalOcean App Platform comment here with your findings. This is such a strange error and I can't entirely pinpoint what is causing it. Sometimes it randomly appears and then is ok again for a new deploys. It makes no sense. 

When I "collectstatic" from dev/local to cloud (AWS) so that all static files are already in place before the real deploy, and then do a "Force Rebuild" with "clear cache" on the app it seems to work fine. Otherwise it appears to just randomly break. The error message itself really doesn't help either. I'll keep digging.

Comment: in my case, copying the key from properties section of the file in s3 and pasting it in the event solved it. It actually had '.PDF' as extension. Error occurred when I  was executing with '.pdf'

Answer (score 6):

Your code is correct.

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (404) when calling
> the HeadObject operation: Not Found

This error is thrown when the object you are trying to fetch is not present in the bucket.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer was perfect as is and provided me with all the information I needed to solve my problem. In my case, I just added a try/except botocore.exceptions.ClientError around the download call which results in catching the error when the expected file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the aiobotocore solved the issue for me.

```
pip install --upgrade aiobotocore
```